# How to generate a dataframe from .txt files in multiple directories?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, directory, subdirectory

I have a directory ".../data" in which have multiple subdirectories whose names are a serial number plus some useless information - e.g. "17448_2017_Jul_2017_Oct", where the first number on it is the serial number. Inside each subdirectory, I have four ".txt" files whose lines/rows have the information of date and time, and an attribute of a certain type, say humidity, all named the same way in each subdirectory - e.g. "2019-01-29  03:11:26    54.7". The first eight lines on each .txt file top should be dropped as well.

What I am trying to program: A code that generates a data frame for each serial number with the subdirectory serial number in the subdirectory name in a column called 'Machine', date/time as the data frame index and each type of an attribute as a column such as  atr1, atr2, atr3, and atr4.

My first trial was something as:

```
 path = "/home/marlon/Shift One/Projeto Philips/Consolidação de Arquivos/dados"

for i in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i)) and '17884' in i:
        with open(path + i, 'r') as f:
```

But, as you can see, I'm completely lost... :/

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could try sth like this (note this is intended to be a start for test and feedback, because I can't test this on my mobile at the moment):

```
import os
import pandas as pd 
path = "/home/marlon/Shift One/Projeto Philips/Consolidação de Arquivos/dados/"

df = pd.DataFrame()

for fld in os.listdir(path):
    subfld = path + fld
    if os.path.isdir(subfld):
        aux = pd.DataFrame()
        sn = fld.split('_')[0]
        for file in os.listdir(subfld):
            filepath = os.path.join(subfld, file)
            if os.path.isfile(filepath):
                new_col = pd.read_fwf(filepath, colspecs=[(0, 19), (20, -1)], skiprows=8, header=None, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)
                aux = pd.concat([aux, new_col], axis=1)
        aux['Machine'] = sn
        df = df.append(aux)
```

However, I wonder if your 4 measurement files per folder all have the same index time values, otherwise there will be a problem concatenating them.

Comment: Hey man, it looks nice. Due to the time zone difference I still didn’t try it. But I’ll do it in couple of minutes and I’ll tell you how is it. Thanks!!!

Comment: Here is what I've got:

`File "/home/marlon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4843, in construction_error
    passed, implied))

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 201590), indices imply (2, 201586)`

Comment: It seems line 29.

`File "/home/marlon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 5699, in combine_concat_plans
    raise ValueError("Plan shapes are not aligned")`

Comment: What in my post is your line 29?

Comment: ‘aux[“Machine”]=an  sorry for not telling before. :)

Comment: Can you print after the program stops what's in `sn` and `aux`? Hard to believe that this is causing an error, because `sn` is a single value which is copied `len(aux)` times to fill the column called `Machine`

Comment: Sure! I’m on the phone now because it is too late, but I’ll do it later, ok!? :)

Comment: Ok, please check also if in the current subfolder the 4 txt files _really_ have the same length/number of lines...

Comment: About it I can tell they don’t!

Comment: They aren’t the same length. :/

Comment: Ok, that's the reason for the error imo. As a first test, you can simply add the kwarg `nrows=100` (or whatever you are sure what the least common number of lines could be) to the pandas import command (`read_fwf` here). However, how to finally deal with such errors depends strongly on what you like to do with the data and what differences _exactly_ occur from file to file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193923/discussion-between-marlon-henrique-teixeira-and-spghttcd).

Comment: IMO the time base of your four data files is so different, that they are not meant to be put into one common dataframe. At least not at import and only perhaps later, after some investigation. So my approach would be in your case to import the four different data files per folder into four different dataframes. Once this is done, you can plot them separately, in one plot - however you like. And if you really have to calculate something based on several or all of them, you still can try to give them a common base by resampling for example. _(For some reason chat didn't take this message...)_